# Getting org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2, logfactory

I was working on upgrading log4j1.x to log4j2.x. For that I replace log4j1.x with log4j2.17.1(get both log4j-core and api) and my pom file has commons-logging with version 1.2. I had replaces log4j.properties with log4j2.properties file. After deploying changes, in EC2 instance i am getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:804)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
```

Pom file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I do have commons-logging.properties file which has code below.

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log = org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

In my project, they have used logger as mentioned below:

A.java

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class A{
public static Log logger = LogFactory.get(A.class);
}
```

Can someone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly configured Jakarta Commons Logging to use Log4j 1.x. Since you don't have it on the classpath an error is generated.

Remark that Log4j 1.x and Log4j 2.x are not compatible. To bind JCL to Log4j 2.x you need to:

- remove/comment the entry in `commons-logging.properties` that forces JCL to use Log4j 1.x,
- add the appropriate Log4j 2.x binding:

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

**Edit**: Regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71617732/getting-org-apache-commons-logging-logconfigurationexception/71634275?noredirect=1#comment126602346_71634275): since `log4j-jcl` has a transitive dependency on `commons-logging`, you could remove the latter from the POM file (and use the default `compile` scope for `log4j-jcl`).

However the common practice is to add as `compile` dependencies all the artifacts that you use directly in your code (cf. [Maven's dependency:analyze goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html)) and don't rely on transitive dependencies (which can change). Therefore you should have both `commons-logging` in the `compile` scope and `log4j-jcl` in the `runtime` scope.

You can also consider switching from JCL to the Log4j 2.x API, which is more easy to use (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html)). In such a case you should remove `commons-logging` from your dependencies, but keep `log4j-jcl` to allow your other dependencies to use JCL.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 
I have 2 doubts now:
1. Shall I remove commons-logging dependency and place log4j-jcl in my pom file?
2. Since my A.java class is using LogFactory so shall I need to LogManager in replacement of LogFactory or LogFactory will work even after removing commons-logging dependency?

Comment: @007_programmer: I added some clarifications to the answer.